# Cannot resolve 'sport_details' given 1 input columns in Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to define a schema for my json in Spark. I have this error :

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve
> '`sport_details`' given input columns: [user_agent, modified_at,
> datamatrix_content, player_id, created_by, device_advertisers_id,
> device_type, betslips, created_by_app, created_by_user, status,
> device_id, uid, created_at, created_by_partner];;

Here is my code :

```
      val mySchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("uid", StringType, true),
    StructField("modified_at", TimestampType, true),
    StructField("created_at", TimestampType, true),
    StructField("datamatrix_content", StringType, true),
    StructField("created_by", StringType, true),
    StructField("created_by_app", StringType, true),
    StructField("created_by_partner", StringType, true),
    StructField("created_by_user", StringType, true),
    StructField("status", StringType, true),
    StructField("player_id", StringType, true),
    StructField("device_type", StringType, true),
    StructField("device_id", StringType, true),
    StructField("user_agent", StringType, true),

    StructField("betslips", StructType(Array(
      StructField("game_name", StringType, true),
      StructField("type_id", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("expires_at", TimestampType, true),
      StructField("enabled", BooleanType, true),


      StructField("sport_details", StructType(Array(
        StructField("grid_id", IntegerType, true),
        StructField("double_count", IntegerType, true),
        StructField("triple_count", IntegerType, true)
      ))))))))
```

And here my json :

```
[
  {
    "uid": "*",
    "modified_at": "*",
    "created_at": "*",
    "datamatrix_content": "string",
    "created_by": "string",
    "created_by_app": "*",
    "created_by_partner": "string",
    "created_by_user": "string",
    "status": "pending",
    "player_id": "string",
    "device_type": "mobile/ios",
    "device_id": "string",
    "device_advertisers_id": "string",
    "user_agent": "string",

    "betslips": [
      {
        "game_name": "*",
        "type_id": 0,
        "expires_at": "*",
        "enabled": true,
 
        "sport_details": [
          {
            "grid_id": 122,
            "double_count": 2,
            "triple_count": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

betslip and user details are ArrayType in your json, so you should add those in schema as below

```
val mySchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("uid", StringType, true),
  StructField("modified_at", TimestampType, true),
  StructField("created_at", TimestampType, true),
  StructField("datamatrix_content", StringType, true),
  StructField("created_by", StringType, true),
  StructField("created_by_app", StringType, true),
  StructField("created_by_partner", StringType, true),
  StructField("created_by_user", StringType, true),
  StructField("status", StringType, true),
  StructField("player_id", StringType, true),
  StructField("device_type", StringType, true),
  StructField("device_id", StringType, true),
  StructField("user_agent", StringType, true),
  StructField("betslips", ArrayType(
    StructType(Array(
      StructField("game_name", StringType, true),
      StructField("type_id", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("expires_at", TimestampType, true),
      StructField("enabled", BooleanType, true),
      StructField("sport_details", ArrayType(
        StructType(Array(
          StructField("grid_id", IntegerType, true),
          StructField("double_count", IntegerType, true),
          StructField("triple_count", IntegerType, true)
        ))
      ))
    ))
  ))
))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have a wrong schema specified.
betslips is of ArrayType and then the element type is a StructType.
Aslo the json seems to start with annonymous collection.

The correct schema should be:

```
val mySchema = StructType(
            Array(
                StructField("uid", StringType, true),
                StructField("modified_at", TimestampType, true),
                StructField("created_at", TimestampType, true),
                StructField("datamatrix_content", StringType, true),
                StructField("created_by", StringType, true),
                StructField("created_by_app", StringType, true),
                StructField("created_by_partner", StringType, true),
                StructField("created_by_user", StringType, true),
                StructField("status", StringType, true),
                StructField("player_id", StringType, true),
                StructField("device_type", StringType, true),
                StructField("device_id", StringType, true),
                StructField("user_agent", StringType, true),
            
                StructField("betslips", ArrayType(
                    StructType(
                        Array(
                            StructField("game_name", StringType, true),
                            StructField("type_id", IntegerType, true),
                            StructField("expires_at", TimestampType, true),
                            StructField("enabled", BooleanType, true),
                        
                            ArrayType("sport_details", 
                                StructType(Array(
                                    StructField("grid_id", IntegerType, true),
                                    StructField("double_count", IntegerType, true),
                                    StructField("triple_count", IntegerType, true)
                                ))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ))
            )
        )
```